# jQuery Masonry: Sorting images

Tags: jquery, image, sorting, jquery-masonry

I'm using jQuery Masonry for aligning images on my site. All images have the same width but different heights. Depending on which order they are loaded they are placed, well weird.

This is what I get:

[image: What I get]

And this is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Is this something I should fix with jQuery or maybe somehow change the order they are loaded from the server with PHP? Then how?

Code so far:

```
var $container = $('#imageAlbum');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.image'
      columnWidth: 230;
  });

});
```

CSS for the images

```
.image{
     margin: 10px;
     float: left;
     width: 230px;
}
```

**ADDED**

Made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DXCDv/2/

Comment: I believe masonry has been replaced by [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). How are you initializing the masonry set? Can you share some code?

Comment: @KaleMcNaney They are 2 different plugins, masonry is free but isotope is not.

Comment: Good call, @undefined. For non-commercial/personal use, isotope [requires a license](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/license.html) and yes, it is a different plugin. Still willing to help debug the masonry issue if you can share some code. Didn't mean to mistakenly plug isotope.

Comment: @KaleMcNaney That's nice of you, it is not my question :).

Comment: Is it possible you're missing a comma after `itemSelector : '.image'` and an unnecessary semi-colon after column-width?

Comment: Adding the comma doesn't help and removing the semi-colon just puts all the images in a vertical row.

Comment: To do quick syntax checking on js, I recommend [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) or the Chrome developer console.

Comment: Just checked with the Chrome developer console and it suggested me to remove the semi-colon, which I did. Then I increased the columnWidth and I'm back where I began.

Comment: OK, good to know the syntax is correct. I think what you want is the [isRTL parameter option](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#isrtl) in your masonry call. Example here `http://jsfiddle.net/MPcGa/`

Comment: Tested that and now the top two images (img1 & img2) just switched place with each other.

Comment: RTL just changes the order on each row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17418/discussion-between-kale-mcnaney-and-oskwish)

Answer (score 0):

Typical issue, typical solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084453/963514). Would be easier to debug, if you'd share your development jsfiddle, jsbin or online sandbox.

**UPDATE** You just forgot to specify a height. Masonry needs width and height. See [changed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VM3Rg/). If you're intending to load your images dynamically, you need to use the [imagesLoaded method](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html) which triggers Masonry *after* the images have loaded and the plugin *knows their widths and heights* to layout properly.